FormBuilder submission that needs approval in searchkit
Is it possible for SearchKit to extract data from AfformSubmission that has yet to be approved? We want to create a Scheduled Reminder that uses the SearchKit and extract the email inside the data column. I wonder if that is possible so the results will just have an email or other info from data.
Edit: If it is possible for an intervention during Scheduled Reminder via extension hooks, what do you recommend?

I'd recommend you ask your question with more of the backstory, instead of such specific questions about your assumed implementation.
